# Add text with js after animation ends

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I'm trying to add a text (that is a countdown ) made with JS that works, but only after another text (made with JS) has finished it's animation, but I'm struggling with it.
I've tried some methods but nothing worked for me, I'm new but I'm a quick learner.

Can someone help me out?

Here is a part of my code:

HTML

```js
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Feb 1, 2019 11:59:20").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get todays date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Display the result in the element with id="countdown"
  document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = days + " days left " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

  // Add text to <h1 id="fade">
  var comingSoon = document.getElementById("fade");
  comingSoon.innerHTML = 'COMING SOON';

  // If the count down is finished, write some text 
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    //document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Well.. what are you waiting for?";
    // If countdown finished, remove the <p id="countdown">
      var parent = document.getElementById("comingSoonContainer");
      var child = document.getElementById("countdown");
      parent.removeChild(child);

    // Create new <p> with text
      var para = document.createElement("p");
      var node = document.createTextNode("New Paragraph works fine.");
      para.appendChild(node);

      var element = document.getElementById("comingSoonContainer");
      element.appendChild(para);

      // Replace <h1> with text
      para = document.createElement("h1");
      node = document.createTextNode("Enjoooooy !!");
      para.appendChild(node);

      parent = document.getElementById("comingSoonContainer");
      child = document.getElementById("fade");
      parent.replaceChild(para, child);

    //document.getElementById("fade").innerHTML = "Enjoy !!";
  }

}, 1000);
```

```css
#countdown {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size: /*1.3em;*/ 3em;
    color: #ffffff;
    /*including fade animation*/
    -webkit-animation-name: fade;
      -webkit-animation-duration: 12s;
      animation-name: fade;
      animation-duration: 12s;
}

    /* Fade animation */
    #fade {
      -webkit-animation-name: fade;
      -webkit-animation-duration: 8s;
      animation-name: fade;
      animation-duration: 8s;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes fade {
      from {opacity: .0} 
      to {opacity: 1}
    }

    @keyframes fade {
      from {opacity: .0} 
      to {opacity: 1}
    }
```

```html
    <div id="comingSoonContainer"> 
      <h1 id="fade"></h1>
      <p id="countdown"></p>
    
     </div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: 
First, the problem is with your CSS styles for the countdown paragraph . You set the paragraph color to white and since your body is white as well, that's why you never see the countdown. But if you change the color to black for instance, you'll see your countdown.

Second, I added an animationend event to your fade element and put the  setInterval inside it.

Here is the CSS you need to change:

```
#countdown {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size: /*1.3em;*/ 3em;
    color: #000;                      // Color was #ffffff
    /*including fade animation*/
    -webkit-animation-name: fade;
      -webkit-animation-duration: 12s;
      animation-name: fade;
      animation-duration: 12s;
}
```

And here is the javascript:

```
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Feb 1, 2019 11:59:20").getTime();

// Add text to <h1 id="fade">
var comingSoon = document.getElementById("fade");
comingSoon.innerHTML = 'COMING SOON';

comingSoon.addEventListener('animationend', ()=>{


// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get todays date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

 // Display the result in the element with id="countdown"
  document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = days + " days left " + hours     + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

});

 });
```

I removed the part where you check for distance just because it had nothing to do with what you asked for help. You can add it though.

But here is the working fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/fwxL1sj4/33/

Comment: Thank you, that works, but hasn't solved my problem. So, in the moment it hits 0, I want to remain like this and fade out, than to be replaced with another text (another fade in), I've tried alone, but it doesn't work

Comment: No problem. But how is it that it didn’t answer your question though? You asked about how to add text (fade it in) after some other text has finished being animated, and I solved that. What you’re asking now is a different question that is not in your problem’s description. So you should at least mark the answer for this question and then make a new post about your other problem or edit your description but having an update on the description, but make sure you state the update. But in both ways, you should mark this question as accepted at least

Answer (score 0):

There is animation callbacks:

```js
function callFunction(){

}
var element=document.getElementById('fade');
element.addEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd", callfunction,false);
element.addEventListener("animationend", callfunction,false);
element.addEventListener("onaimationend", callfunction,false);
```

Comment: (excess curly bracket)